# segment does not contain sync frame

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, video-encoding

Whenever I split a video using Apple's `mediafilesegmenter`, using the following command: `medifilesegmenter video.ts -t 10`. I get the following error for each segment except the first:

```
segment does not contain sync frame
```

Before splitting I've converted the .MP4 version to a .TS with the following command:

```
avconv -y -i video.mp4 -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s 640x480 -vcodec libx264 -b 64k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 7 -trellis 0 -refs 0 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 64k -bufsize 64k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 30 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 640:480 -g 30 -async 2 sample_64.ts
```

Can anyone tell me why this error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by updating to the latest version of ffmpeg instead of using avconv. The command I finally used to convert the `MP4` videos:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s 640x480 -vcodec libx264 -b 150k -flags +loop -cmp chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 7 -trellis 0 -refs 0 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 150k -bufsize 150k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 30 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 640:480 -g 30 -async 2 sample_150.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because I pictures are needed at the 10 second point. Find your video frame rate. If you want 10 second segments you need an I frame at every 10th second. So you can insert one every seconds, 2 seconds, 5 seconds or 10 seconds. To do that set sc_threshold to 0 and keyint_interval to frame_rate*[one of 1,2,5,10] depending on the key frame interval you want.

Comment: I just tried it with the following command. I set the keyint_min to 30 to add one every second and set the sc_threshold to zero, but it still gave the exact same error. `avconv -y -i video.mp4 -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s 640x480 -vcodec libx264 -b 240k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 7 -trellis 0 -refs 0 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 30 -sc_threshold 0 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 240k -bufsize 240k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 30 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 640:480 -g 30 -async 2 output.ts`

Comment: The problem was my version of `avconv`/`ffmpeg`, after updating to version 1.1 the problem was solved.